# PSD matrix characteristics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A very stupid question that would solve a lot of troubles in my life:
Is the product of vector of positive values with a positive semi definite matrix always positive vector? 
I have to analyze when does x'C>0 hold, where x is a vector with positive entries, and C is PSD matrix.
Or in other words can I divide the whole inequality by the PSD matrix such that the inequality does not change the sign?

Answer (score 1):

No. Not even with positive-definite.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix} 1\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\5\end{bmatrix}.
$$